# use a different socket than /dev/log, system-wide

Tags: debian, android, syslog, bind-mount, debootstrap

Is there a way to make a whole Debian (Jessie) installation use a different syslog socket than `/dev/log` (like, for example, `/tmp/my-other-log`) ?

Reason: I'm running Debian Jessie in a chroot environment within a Android 4 environment. `/dev/log` in Android is a *directory*, so I can bind-mount that path to a different file. To make `rsyslogd` work with all debian programs, I need `/dev/log` to be a custom socket, or make all programs use a different path.

- Can I override the path using some **environment variable** perhaps?
- Since I prepare the Debian installation using `debootstrap`, is there something I can do at build time? Maybe patch the libc (or where ever syslog code is hidden)?

Answer (score 1):

Patching the `libc` binary seems to work:

```
sed -i --binary -e 's/\/dev\/log/\/SLG\/log/' /lib/*/libc-*.so
```

This causes programs to send syslog messages to `/SLG/log` instead of `/dev/log` (note the same length of the strings).

However, I consider this a **dirty hack** and I really hope someone comes up with a better solution...